# How can I convert PDF pages to images?

Tags: python, pypdf

I need save PDF pages as images.

Is this possible with pypdf?

Comment: pypdf will not render a PDF to an image (I'm the maintainer of pypdf). I modified your question for this reason

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no good way to do this, not with pyPdf or any other libraries I've seen. PIL supports writing, but not reading PDF so it doesn't help here, either. Such support would be quite nice to have. I'd recommend using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) as a work around, you can call it with [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) from your script, and have it handle the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) also has [Python bindings](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/) available, so you could output your images without having to use `subprocess`