# How to save pages in a PDF as images using Python

Tags: python-2.7, pdf

I want to save all the pages in the PDF document as images using python.
I already tried Imagemagick and pypdf. The results are not good with my type of document (containing graphs, old scanned documents).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert PDF pages to images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508641/how-can-i-convert-pdf-pages-to-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Imagemagick to convert PDF to say PNG, one can specify the density to rasterize the PDF at high resolution. Then you can resize back down if you want. For example,

```
convert -density 300 image.pdf -resize WxH image.png
```

If your PDF is CMYK rather RGB, then add -colorspace sRGB right after -density 300 and before reading the image.pdf.

If that is not good enough increase the density to 600 and try again.

WxH is the final images size that you want.

If using Imagemagick 7, then replace convert with magick

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579708/get-rows-and-columns-of-text-lines-in-a-scanned-document-in-python-opencv can u plz look in to it @mike

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579708/get-rows-and-columns-of-text-lines-in-a-scanned-document-in-python-opencv can u plz look in to it @Alex

Comment: @AlexanderWhatley